# Valid interpretations of the (first) て-form in 何かを犠牲にして、その上で、平和は成り立っている。

Tags: grammar, て-form

What are the valid interpretations of the (first) て-form in the following sentence?

> **何かを犠牲にして**、その上で、平和は成り立っている。

I'm having difficulties assigning a definite meaning to this sentence. There seems to be a couple of forms the て-form could imply that all make sense in context (in English at least), which I've listed below. Can any of them be excluded for grammatical reasons?

```
 何かを犠牲にした

 (平和が)何かを犠牲にしている

 (not平和が)何かを犠牲にしている

 何かを犠牲にする　(habitual)
```

The full context is:

> しかし、平和はただではありません。**何かを犠牲にして**、その上で、平和は成り立っている。昔は自分の可愛い子供達でした。

Comment: What do you imagine it means?

Comment: It seemed like either 私達は何かを犠牲にしている。　その上で、平和は成り立っている or　私達は何かを犠牲にした。　その上で、平和は成り立っている were the most likely candidates.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. What do you think it means in English? (rather than which type of て form do you think it is)

Comment: Crudely, either that their freedom is built on top of sacrifices they have made, or sacrifices they're still making. Or that freedom more generally is built out of sacrifices being made, but wouldn't it have to be 平和は成り立つ then?

Comment: @(平和/not平和が)"Peace" (an inanimate object) cannot literally make a sacrifice. If it is to be meaningful, it needs to be interpreted metaphorically, ie "we are making a sacrifice (for peace)".

Comment: @Svante, 成り立つ is a change-of-state verb (or whatever your preferred nomenclature is), so the perfective state-of-having-been-built is 成り立っている. 成り立つ could be used as a habitual.

Comment: @dainichi "so the perfective state-of-having-been-built is 成り立っている." So that action is completed, so to speak, and 何かを犠牲にして has to proceed that, right? And consequently be completed itself. The rest of the text shows that the sacrifices are still on-going, though, which to me clashes a bit with the above. That's why I wanted to to know if it's necessarily that 何かを犠牲にして has to proceed 成り立っている, or if there could be overlap such as with 何かを犠牲にする. Or something. As you can probably tell I have a lot of problems with the て-form!

Answer (score 3):

> しかし、平和はただではありません。何かを犠牲にして、その上で、平和は成り立っている。　昔は自分の可愛い子供達でした。

In parts, "しかし、平和はただではありません。"

However, peace is not free. (natural English order: "Peace, however, is not free")

Part 2: "何かを犠牲にして"

"Something becomes a sacrifice" or "something is used as a sacrifice"

Part 3: "その上で、平和は成り立っている。"

"Through this, peace is made"

Part 4: "昔は自分の可愛い子供達でした。"

"In the past, this was your own cute children"

Answer (score 2):

Its difficult to give a full translation of the sentence with the limited context you have given (and I was not sure what to make of your other notes) but, regarding the てーform:

It links phrases. The link is usually to describe one of the following three things:

> (1) "Cause and effect"*, eg: お腹が痛くて、歩けない
>
> (2) Sequential actions, eg: 図書館へ行って、勉強した
>
> (3) A common topic, eg: このレストランは安くて、おいしい

In this case the te-form is describing "cause and effect" (one is the result of, or at least, the reason or condition of the other):

> 何かを犠牲にして  ->  平和が成り立っている
> giving something up/making some sacrifice -> peace was concluded.

その上で is similar to 〜た上で〜 which is equivalent to ~てから (~ after). It contributes to the literary effect of the writing, emphasising that peace will come only after a sacrifice has been made.

Regarding a translation:

My rough, somewhat loose, translation of the extract found by Choko is as follows:

> 平和はただではありません。何かを犠牲にして、その上で平和は成り立っているのです。昔はそれが、自分の可愛い子供達でした。幼い兵士が、地獄のような戦場で戦い、死んで、国を守ってくれていたのです
>
> Peace does not come at any price. It is established after the required sacrifices have been made. A long time ago those sacrifices were our precious children. Our young soldiers fought and died for us, protecting our country in battlefields that resembled Hell.

*Note:  "Cause and effect" is used to indicate a reason or causal link between the two actions. "Sequential actions" is used to indicate cases where the te-form simply describes the order in which the actions occur.  It is more important to focus on the nature of the examples than the English labels.

Comment: 「昔は自分の可愛い子供達でした。」は、「昔(=70年前やWW2時など)は、その犠牲になったものが、自分の大事な子供たちでした。」（戦争中などの昔には、自分の子供が犠牲になって(=戦地へ行って)、その上で平和が成り立っていた。）

Comment: ああ、ここにありました。「昔はそれが、自分の可愛い子供達でした。幼い兵士が、地獄のような戦場で戦い、死んで、国を守ってくれていたのです。」http://bottega-g2.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2009-11-05

Comment: @Choko: I should not guess the context! Thank you. I will make a revision.

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking is cause-effect, but I think it's actually a sequential action. At least looking at a literal translation.
- You sacrifice something, and it's on that (sacrifice) that peace is founded(/arises).

Comment: "Cause and effect" is used to indicate a reason or causal link between the two actions. "Sequential actions" is used to indicate cases where the te-form simply describes the order in which the actions occur. We can quibble but it is more important to focus on the nature of the examples than the English labels (which I have not made up myself)